# How to create self contained exe file as output of my application

Tags: executable, save, desktop-application

im trying to figure away to be able to export/save user ( banch of files/htmls ) 
to one single self contained exe file . and i have no idea how to do it .
i was thinking about using windows gcc port , but its GPL and my app is commercial.
how do i approach to solve such thing ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a self extracting exe.

or

You could use vbc or csc from the .net framework, they're shipped as part of the framework (not sure about the new 3.5 client stuff)

Comment: A self-extracting exe file can be created e.g. with IExpress (it's included with Windows) which you can configure via a config file.

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know about that one, ta

Comment: well i need not self extracted , but self contained 
that is the final result will be one exe files with no other files

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your feelings about script languages [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) might be just the thing for this. Aut2Exe.exe (the compiler) is only 340KB I have done this kind of thing before to make an application that creates other applications. In [this post on the AutoIt forums](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/index.php?s=&showtopic=96425&view=findpost&p=693185) it is explained how to do exactly this with AutoIt. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

try using Advanced Installer for windows...
It is a closed source application for creating .exe,.msi installer files for the applications.

Answer (score 0):

Why GCC when there's a bunch of ways to create self-extracting exe's (and run a command when you extract)?

[Commercial example (Zip 2 Secure EXE)](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ChilkatSfx.asp)

Comment: Or use the free IExpress which is already on every Windows PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try IExpress (windows) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346760.aspx

Run > IExpress